# Bootstrap 4.5 Tab always opens page instead of tab content in Blazor

Tags: c#, html, blazor, .net-5, blazor-webassembly

I'm new to Blazor and just made a new project using WASM, Bootstrap 4.5 and .NET 5. I'm trying to make a tab layout work but whenever I click my tabs, they attempt to navigate to a new page, rather than opening the associated tab content.

I am not quite sure what it is I'm doing wrong here, as looking at pages of examples shows I'm doing what the examples are doing (Although it's possible I've simply grown blind to my own code now.)

Here is the code that generates the tabs and their content from my `GameDetails.razor` page:

```cs
@if (_game != null)
{
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill" role="tablist">
        @foreach (Tuple<string, string> key in _parsedMappings.Keys)
        {
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link @(_isFirstElem == true ? "active" : "")"
                   id="@key.Item2.Replace(" ", "")-tab"
                   data-toggle="tab"
                   href="#@key.Item2.Replace(" ", "")"
                   role="tab"
                   aria-controls="@key.Item2.Replace(" ", "")"
                   aria-selected="@(_isFirstElem == true ? "true" : "false")">@key.Item1, @key.Item2</a>
            </li>
            _isFirstElem = false;
        }
        @if (_isFirstElem == false) _isFirstElem = true;
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="tabContent">
        @foreach (KeyValuePair<Tuple<string, string>, List<Mapping>> pair in _parsedMappings)
        {
            <div class="tab-pane fade show @(_isFirstElem == true ? "active" : "")"
                 id="@pair.Key.Item2.Replace(" ", "")"
                 role="tabpanel"
                 aria-labelledby="@pair.Key.Item2.Replace(" ", "")-tab">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    @foreach (Mapping mapping in pair.Value)
                    {
                        <li class="list-group-item">
                            <b>@mapping.FunctionName</b>: <i>@mapping.Key</i>
                        </li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
            _isFirstElem = false;
        }
    </div>
}
```

It produces this html:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" id="Keyboard&Mouse-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#Keyboard&Mouse" role="tab" aria-controls="Keyboard&Mouse" aria-selected="true">PC, Keyboard & Mouse</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link " id="NintendoSwitchJoycons-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#NintendoSwitchJoycons" role="tab" aria-controls="NintendoSwitchJoycons" aria-selected="false">Nintendo Switch, Nintendo Switch Joycons</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="Keyboard&Mouse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="Keyboard&Mouse-tab">
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item">...</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">...</li>
      ...
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade show " id="NintendoSwitchJoycons" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="NintendoSwitchJoycons-tab">
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item">...</i></li>
      <li class="list-group-item">...</i></li>
      ...
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which to my knowledge is correctly formatted. So I am not quite sure why the tab tries to navigate to a web page instead of opening the tab content.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the "&" symbol from id="" attributes

Comment: Hmm that didn't seem to help me. It still exhibits the same behaviour.

Comment: I eventually solved it by just making some javascript to take care of the showing/hiding of my content tabs.